# How to make dashed or dotted columns for b&w printing in an MSChart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am making a column chart and I need to differentiate columns in black and white format.

I know how to change colors:

```
mychart.Series["MyName"].Color = Color.MidnightBlue;
```

But I do not know how to fill a column with a dashed or dotted pattern.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-default-cell-styles-for-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution: You can set a **`BackHatchStyle`**, which is a [ChartHatchStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.charthatchstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2) , e.g.:

```
 yourSeries.BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.DarkHorizontal;
```

Those hatch patterns are made for exactly this job. And combined with setting the `Color` and the `BackSecondaryColor` there are even more variations:

[image]

Column chart with 4 hatch styles and one custom fill pattern.

As you can see **each data point may have its own style**. Note that afaik you are limited to the **54** elements in the enumeration and can't change e.g. the scale.

---

If that isn't good enough you can create a **tiling image** and set it as the **`BackImage`**, as I did for the 3rd point.

For this you can **either** use a bitmap from the disk **or** you can add an image created on the fly to the chart's `Images` collection. This will then be a `NamedImage` and the name you set is what you use.

Example:

```
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(10, 12);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.ForestGreen))
    using (SolidBrush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Maroon))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Silver);
        g.FillRectangle(b1, 0, 3, 10, 4);
        g.FillRectangle(b2, 0, 9, 10, 3);

        chart1.Images.Add(new NamedImage("tile3cols", bmp));
    }
```

Now you can use it:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[2].BackImage = "tile3cols";
```

You could even combine both and use a `HatchBrush` plus a scaled `Graphics` to use the hatch patterns at a larger scale..

Comment: I would never do such customized solution))))

Comment: Hehe. Btw: I took the liberty to improve a little on your post to make it easier to find.